# Finding the maximum of unparameterized 2D data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matlab, dataset

I have a set "Z" of values, one for each combination of (X,Y), given on a grid.  I would like to estimate the location of the maximum of Z (expected to lie near the center of the dark blue pixels).  The maximum need not lie on one of the discrete (x,y) pairs defined by the vectors.  The array was created such that there is not really a direct way to define the analytic function for Z(X,Y).

Currently, the only thing that I know to do is marginalize over X and Y, respectively, fit a 1-D function (perhaps a Gaussian) to each in order to get an explicit analytic expression, minimize along each direction independently, and then just use the x^ and y^ of the minimum values for each of these as the coordinates of the 2D minimum.

Is there a better way to do this (conceptually)?

Is there a way to do this using the Z array directly, that does not rely on approximating X and Y as specific distributions? Even in this case, the minimum does not have to fall on the grid defined by X and Y.

Thank you!

---

***Additional Information regarding Z***:

- Z is essentially an 2D array of log-likelihood values, and should not have zeros; all elements of Z are less than zero.

Comment: A data set is a data set, you don't maximize the data set itself. Am I right in thinking you have a set of z values, one for each combination of (x,y) which are given on a grid, and you wish to find the (x,y) pair where z is greatest? Or can you find z for *any* combination of x and y if needed? Do you need to estimate a value not on the grid of values we have here?

Comment: Yes, that description is correct, and I need to estimate a value that is not necessarily on the grid.

Comment: I asked about several things, so I'm not sure which of the things I said is correct. Could you be explicit, by making an edit to your question, please?

Comment: I don't wish to repeat myself, but please *change your question*. You should not expect people to read comment threads to get a clear idea what you are asking about.

Comment: @Glen_b  Thank you for your suggestions regarding corrections to both the title and question, and my apologies - I missed your initial request to edit the question.

Comment: I am unsure why you're fitting functions -- does this function of x and y have noise in it, or is it smooth? If you must fit a function kind of looks like a bivariate gaussian (in which case, the log of it would be a nice quadratic function of a two-vector). Can you give more context?

Comment: @Glen_b when I plot Z as just a function of x and y it appears fairly smooth.  Fitting the functions was a suggestion that I received in order to get an explicit analytic expression to minimize.  I am trying to find out if there is a better way.

Comment: Is z positive/ can it have zeroes/ what does log-z look like?

Comment: @Glen_b:  Z is essentially a 2D array of log-likelihood values, and should not have zeros. The values of Z are all negative in the example shown in the figure.  I have included additional plots, including log(-Z), in the edited question.
Thanks for your help in clarification - this is my first post.

Comment: The information that you're dealing with a likelihood is kind of critical. Why do you have it on a grid? Why not use standard optimization algorithms that are likely to require far fewer function evaluations?

Comment: Assuming you *must* use the grid: for moderate to large sample sizes, near the optimum, a log-likelihood should be nearly quadratic; you could do a few steps of [coordinate descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) (just on the grid values), followed (perhaps) by one stage of a parallel-tangent type approach, probably just using linear or quadratic interpolation between grid points (just in case the x & y are highly correlated). At that stage you should be close enough to take nearby grid values and start trying to fit a quadratic.

Comment: @Glen_b:  The reason that I tried to be generic before, and why the grid is necessary, is that each of the values in Z is the maximum likelihood of a 10-parameter fit with 8 nuisance parameters.  X and Y are the parameters of interest, and this likelihood was calculated/maximized at each (x,y) on the grid.  
There are several of these sets "Z" calculated on identical grids (X,Y), that I am  co-adding in an attempt to get a combined likelihood distribution that allows 1)the nuisance parameters to float while ...

Comment: 2) approximating the maximum of the 2-dimentional co-added Z array as the maximum likelihood point of the combined data. The whole thing is an approximation.  Does your description of the log-likelihood as quadratic near the optimum still apply in this case?

Comment: One additional clarification to the comment above:  "There are several of these sets "Z" calculated on identical grids (X,Y), but *based on different regions of a third "dimension"*, that I am co-adding in an attempt to get a combined distribution.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'co-adding' there. If the function you're maximizing is still a legitimate likelihood of something, the profile log-likelihood should still be approximately quadratic near the maximum.

Comment: Thank you, I think that helps.  By "coadded", I just meant summed.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense but it's not clear to me what is being summed. Is there any reason you need to be coy about what functions you're dealing with in the question rather than being explicit?

Comment: Being coy was largely unintentional- while my question relates to a specific problem that I am trying to solve, I am trying to understand the correct general method or approach to performing this type of 2D fit, and I thought that I would obscure the issue with too many details.  However, in light of your question, I realize that part of my lack of clarity is that I can't really completely describe the origin of the plots that I was showing.

I have temporarily removed the figures above to generate examples of the same type that can be described completely.  Thanks very much for your patience.

Comment: If $Z$'s are actually log-likelihoods already, why can't they be zero?